# How to avoid "random" errors in WPF Designer in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I do often work with custom Controls in WPF.

I usually define them using a xmlns:

```
xmlns:libcontrols="clr-namespace:innerNamespace;assembly=Assemblyname"
```

This works pretty fine, but sometimes Visual Studio simply seems not beeing able to resolve the classes or whatever. In this case I get errors like

*"The name '' doesnt exist in the namespace ''"* - for Controls beeing used

*"The tag '' doesnt exist in namespace ''"* - when using inheritance through xaml.

*"Cannot locate resource ''"* - when a control is not displayed in the designer

Most times a rebuild solves this issue, simetimes I need to restart VS or rewriting it. Everytime those issues do show up when I am **NOT** even editing those files.

I have no clue why this happens and mostly I dont really know what really solved the issue when it's gone, but sometimes it really takes a lot of time i could use to working, so I'd be glad about any hint or trick no nomore waste anytime for that.

Comment: Does this happen if you don't explicitly specify the assembly name in the xmlns declaration? Or do you need to do this in your case?

Answer (score 0):

These are designer issues, you can try to fix them by closing `XDesProc.exe` from TaskManager. After the process is closed you will be able to reload designer from visual studio. Rebuild and it should work fine.